# VS 2010 DBF File ADO.NET Connection - Read Only - Need to update data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, dbf

In VS2010 VB create a data connection using this:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\EDATA\Working;Extended Properties="dbase 5.0"

However VS2010 says it doesnt support updating the DBF file. Am I using the wrong driver or something?

Answer (score 0):

yes !! specify the file Data Source=G:\EDATA\Working\example.mdf

Comment: The connection properties gives an error if I add the file name to the end of the path like your example. I tried that already, but doesn't work.  In the server explorer I can see all of the DBF files and the properties of each one, so the main connection is working.